# How can I set bounds of a randomly placed object to make sure it doesn't go behind iAd

Tags: ios, xcode, bounds

I have a sphere that is placed randomly on the screen.

```
-(void)PlaceSphere{

sphereX = arc4random() %492;
sphereX = sphereX + 34;
sphereY = arc4random() %249;
sphereY = sphereY + 39;

sphere.center = CGPointMake(sphereX, sphereY);

}
```

I currently have iAd on the application. How can I set it up so that it does not go behind the iAd? I am not using auto layout, but I am using autoresizing.

I tried using

```
sphereY = sphereY + 39 <= 275;
```

This did not work out well as it kept on reappearing on the top edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your iAd is at the bottom of the screen, try taking away the height of the iAd from the `sphereY` "%" value, then adding the height of the iAd at the end of the line.

Like This:

```
sphereY = (arc4random() % (249 - /* iAd height */)) + /* iAd height */
```

If your iAd is at the top of the screen, take away the height but don't add it again.

Like This:

```
sphereY = arc4random() % (249 - /* iAd height */)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you realize what you wrote in this line?

```
sphereY = sphereY + 39 <= 275;
```

This line will basically set `sphereY` to `1` if `sphereY + 39 <= 275`, and `0` otherwise. This is the same as:

```
if (sphereY + 39 <= 275)
{
    sphereY = 1;
} else 
{
    sphereY = 0;
}
```

So, yes, it will be always at either `0` or `1`, which explains why it is at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your Minimum value should be the radius of the sphere. And your Maximum should be the (height of the view) - (height of the iAd + radius of the sphere). The equation for generating a random number between these two values is `arc4random()*(Max - Min) + Min`.